# Newly created users .ssh folder is in the wrong place

Tags: ssh, unix, user-accounts, github

I'm trying to create new users on my Media Temple (dv) 3.5 who have the same access as a beta account. The reason for this is so my development team can use GitHub for source management without breaking permissions and such.

I was able to figure out how to create the users, but when I try to connect to GitHub using `ssh -vT git@github.com` I'm getting an error.

The home directory I've created is at `/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/web_users/username` -- when I log in, `cd ~` puts me in the right place.

However, when I try to connect to GitHub, it's looking for `.ssh/` at `/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh` instead of `/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/web_users/username/.ssh`

I used this command to create the user:

```
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/web_users/username -m -ou 10001 -g psacln -s /bin/bash username
```

Have I missed a step? I've only been dealing in the command line for a short time, and this is my first time dealing with new users. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm finding in $HOME:

```
[username@beta.domain ~]$ echo $HOME
/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/web_users/username
```

This is the output from `ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [000.000.000.000] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
Could not create directory '/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh'.
debug1: identity file /var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'github.com (000.000.000.000)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/.ssh/known_hosts).
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
Connection closed by 000.000.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$HOME` is set to `/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain`. If so, figure out where it set.

You could download the source code, build it and run it under a debugger.

Comment: Here's what I'm finding in $HOME:

`[username@beta.domain ~]$ echo $HOME
/var/www/vhosts/beta.domain/web_users/username`

Comment: Download the source code, build it and run it under a debugger. That's the only thing I can think of.